# Is there a 'getZoomForResolution' in OpenLayers 3?

Tags: openlayers-3

OpenLayers 2 used to have a `getZoomForResolution` method that would give you the zoom level (or closest zoom level) of a given resolution.

I don't see any such method in ol3, for the `ol.View` object that is.  Is there a way to achieve this with what `ol.view` currently have ?

Comment: I don't think it's needed any more. If you want to zoom to a certain resolution use setResolution. http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.View.html#setResolution

Comment: There is no `getZoomForResolution` function. `ol.View` has a `getZoom` function that you can use to get the zoom level corresponding to the current view resolution. That does not work for you?

Comment: My use-case is this.  I want to zoom on the extent of features when they are selected from a grid, but I don't want zoom zoom in too much.  I'm getting the extent of the feature and zoom on it.  But, if it goes to far (let's say max zoom level of 15), I step back by setting the zoom level to 15.  That has the issue of zooming twice.  I'd like to zoom only once, so my idea was to get the 'ideal' zoom level for the extent, as I prefer to zoom on 'fixed' resolutions.

Comment: We've discussed adding a `maxZoom` option to `ol.View#fitExtent`. See https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/issues/2723.

Comment: That would do nicely.  Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will give the next closest integer zoom for a give resolution:

```
function zoomForResolution(resolution) {
    var zoom = 0;
    var r = 156543.03390625; // resolution for zoom 0
    while (resolution < r) {
        r /= 2;
        zoom++;
        if (resolution > r) {
            return zoom;
        }
    }
    return zoom; // resolution was greater than 156543.03390625 so return 0
}

zoomForResolution(40); // 12
```

My brother suggested:

```
var zoom = Math.ceil( (Math.log(resolution) - Math.log(156543.03390625) ) / Math.log(0.5))
```

refining the logarithmic solution for browsers with Math.log2()

```
var zoom = Math.log2(156543.03390625) - Math.log2(resolution);
```

and for IE which does not have log2()

```
var zoom = Math.log(156543.03390625) * Math.LOG2E  - Math.log(resolution) * Math.LOG2E;
```

Comment: Thank you for this! However when I run

```js
var zoom = Math.log2(156543.03390625) - Math.log2(resolution);
```

I'm somehow always off by one - so for me that's:

```js
const zoom2 = Math.log2(156_543.033_906_25) - Math.log2(resolution) - 1;
```

Comment: @Jannis Heil  Zoom levels are based on the world width fitting a single tile. MVT tiles are usually 512 pixels, WMTS/XYZ usually 256. So you may need to adjust for you tile size.

Answer (score 0):

In newer versions of OpenLayers there is a `getZoomForResolution` function now: https://openlayers.org/en/v7.5.2/apidoc/module-ol_View-View.html#getZoomForResolution