# Is getZoomForResolution defined in Open Layers 4? And if so, how do I get it working?

Tags: openlayers

For my map application I'd like to use the ol.View.zoom-property as well as ol.View.resolution property in different functions. According to the Open Layers 4 API documentation, the zoom property is ignored if a resolution is given.
Therefore I'm trying to apply getZoomForResolution, which is documented in the API here:

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.View.html#getZoomForResolution

This is some test code I use:

```
var map, view;
    //initial definition of the map
    function initializeMap(){
        //define osm source and layer
        var osmSource = new ol.source.OSM();
        var osmLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({source: osmSource});
        //define new map object
        map = new ol.Map({
            target:'map',
            view: new ol.View({
                center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([9.83276, 52.36554]),
                resolution:300, // is required in some function
                zoom:10 //ignored as expected according to API, also required in another function
            }),
            layers:[osmLayer]
        });
        var currentResolution = map.getView().getResolution(); // returns 300 as expected
        console.log(map.getView().getZoomForResolution(currentResolution));
    }
```

Unfortunately, I only receive the error "map.getView().getZoomForResolution is not a function". I also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29900520/is-there-a-getzoomforresolution-in-openlayers-3) post, but it's referring to OL 3 and there is no proof given.

So, my question is: is the getZoomForResolution-function not implemented anymore? Or is there a mistake in the way I'm trying to access it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works just fine here. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vePjxa?editors=1011

```
 var osmSource = new ol.source.OSM();
    var osmLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({source: osmSource});
    //define new map object
    map = new ol.Map({
        target:'map',
        view: new ol.View({
            center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([9.83276, 52.36554]),
            resolution:300, // is required in some function
            zoom:10 //ignored as expected according to API, also required in another function
        }),
        layers:[osmLayer]
    });
    var currentResolution = map.getView().getResolution(); // returns 300 as expected
    console.log(map.getView().getZoomForResolution(currentResolution));
```

Do you have a sandbox with it not working?

Comment: Ahh, should have tried that earlier - works in a different environment. Thank you!